# how to resolve dropbox installation error in debian wheezy? 'backend does not support installing files'

Tags: debian, dropbox

Just installed Debian for the first time and one of the first things I have done is attempt to install drop box.  I downloaded the 32 bit debian version from the dropbox site to `/home/user/downloads`.  (I created the downloads directory).

Now when I click on the package in my downloads folder I am given the error message,

```
"not supported
your current backend does not support installing files",
```

which I really dont know what this means so I attempted to install from the command line with the following:

```
mike@debian:~$ sudo dpkg -I dropbox*
[sudo] password for mike:
dpkg: error processing dropbox* (--install):
cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
dropbox*
```

and that is what I got...  now, I am just going to probably compile dropbox from source, but being new to debian I would like to understand the meaning of the error message I received if anyone has any insight.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the output of `ls`?

Comment: ls for which directory specifically?  i have already installed from source now, so the directory for /nautilus-dropbox-1.4.0 is not the same as it was when i wrote the question.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you received means that dpkg is not able to find the file you specified on the command line. Instead of installing dropbox using `sudo dpkg -i dropbox*` try to use the whole pathname and filename instead. Chances are that you have forgotten a capital letter or dpkg is not able to resolve wildcards.

A good trick to check that you have written the correct path and filename is to type a couple of letters for the filename and then press `tab`. If you have typed everything correct, then the whole filename should be auto completed. If not, go back and double check if the folders and file name is written correctly.

Comment: i was able to install dropbox from source, i needed to install several packages from syanptic but that was fine.                     the part i didnt understand, that i was asking about was the error message, not from my first attempting at installing from the cli, but the error message when i attempted to open the downloaded file  that said '' your current backend does not support installing files".

Comment: i guess more specifically, what is the backend? and why would it not support installing?  perhaps it was simply the packages that i had to install to complete the source installation?